# Magento Limiting Collections not working

Tags: magento-1.9, database, adminhtml, collection, grid

I am using following code to get collections of my custom created module,

app/code/local/Promocode/Promogenerator/Block/Adminhtml/Promogenerator/Grid.php

```
<?php

class Promocode_Promogenerator_Block_Adminhtml_Promogenerator_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->setId("promogeneratorGrid");
            $this->setDefaultSort("id");
            $this->setDefaultDir("DESC");
            $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
            $collection = Mage::getModel("promogenerator/promogenerator")
                        ->getCollection()
                        ->addFieldToSelect('*')
                        ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('neq' => '3'));
                        //->setPageSize(20);
                        //->setPageSize(20)
                        //->setCurPage(1);*/
            $this->setCollection($collection);
            echo $collection->load()->getSelect();
            //die();
            //return parent::_prepareCollection();
            return $this;
    }

    public function customerCallback($collection){
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
            $this->addColumn("id", array(
                "header" => Mage::helper("promogenerator")->__("ID"),
                "align" =>"right",
                "width" => "50px",
                "type" => "number",
                "index" => "id",
            ));

            $this->addColumn("roll_id", array(
            "header" => Mage::helper("promogenerator")->__("Roll"),
            "index" => "roll_id",
            'type' => 'options',
            'options'=>Promocode_Promogenerator_Block_Adminhtml_Promogenerator_Grid::getOptionArray5(),             
            ));
            $this->addColumn("promocode", array(
            "header" => Mage::helper("promogenerator")->__("Promocode"),
            "index" => "promocode",
            ));
            $this->addColumn("promo_id", array(
                "header" => Mage::helper("promogenerator")->__("User"),
                "index"  => array('promo_id','share_id'),
                "type"   => 'concat',
                "separator" => '--',
                "filter_index" => "CONCAT(promo_id, '--', share_id)",
            ));
            /*$this->addColumn("share",array(
                "header" => Mage::helper("promogenerator")->__("User"),
                "index"  => "shareinfo",
            ));*/
            $this->addColumn("provider_id", array(
            "header" => Mage::helper("promogenerator")->__("Referrer"),
            "index" => "provider_id",
            ));
            $this->addColumn('status', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('promogenerator')->__('Status'),
                'index' => 'status',
                'type' => 'options',
                'options'=>Promocode_Promogenerator_Block_Adminhtml_Promogenerator_Grid::getOptionArray4(),             
            ));
            /* $this->addColumn('actions', array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('promogenerator')->__('Action'),
                'width'     => 20,
                'sortable'  => false,
                'filter'    => false,
                'renderer'  => Promocode_Promogenerator_Block_Adminhtml_Promogenerator_Grid_Renderer_Action,
            ));*/


        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('sales')->__('CSV')); 
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Excel'));

            return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
           return $this->getUrl("*/*/edit", array("id" => $row->getId()));
    }



    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        $this->setMassactionIdField('id');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('ids');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setUseSelectAll(true);
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('remove_promogenerator', array(
                 'label'=> Mage::helper('promogenerator')->__('Disable'),
                 'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/adminhtml_promogenerator/massRemove'),
                 'confirm' => Mage::helper('promogenerator')->__('Are you sure?')
            ));
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('delete_promogenerator', array(
                 'label'=> Mage::helper('promogenerator')->__('Remove'),
                 'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/adminhtml_promogenerator/massDelete'),
                 'confirm' => Mage::helper('promogenerator')->__('Are you sure?')
            ));
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('enable_promocode', array(
                 'label'=> Mage::helper('promogenerator')->__('Active'),
                 'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/adminhtml_promogenerator/massEnable'),
                 'confirm' => Mage::helper('promogenerator')->__('Are you sure?')
            ));
        return $this;
    }

    static public function getOptionArray4()
    {
        $data_array=array(); 
        $data_array[0]='In Active';
        $data_array[1]='Active';
        $data_array[2]='Disabled';
        return($data_array);
    }
    static public function getValueArray4()
    {
        $data_array=array();
        foreach(Promocode_Promogenerator_Block_Adminhtml_Promogenerator_Grid::getOptionArray4() as $k=>$v){
           $data_array[]=array('value'=>$k,'label'=>$v);        
        }
        return($data_array);

    }

    static public function getOptionArray5()
    {
        $data_array=array(); 
        $data_array[1]='Admin';
        $data_array[2]='User';
        return($data_array);
    }
    static public function getValueArray5()
    {
        $data_array=array();
        foreach(Promocode_Promogenerator_Block_Adminhtml_Promogenerator_Grid::getOptionArray5() as $k=>$v){
           $data_array[]=array('value'=>$k,'label'=>$v);        
        }
        return($data_array);

    }
```

}

The above code works perfectly well for smaller collections, but with large ones the script will eventually run out of memory and display the blank page error.

I used `setPage(20)` to limit the collections, but its not working.

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
        {
                $collection = Mage::getModel("promogenerator/promogenerator")
                            ->getCollection()
                            ->addFieldToSelect('*')
                            ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('neq' => '3'))
                            ->setPageSize(20);              
                $this->setCollection($collection);
                //echo $collection->load()->getSelect();
                //die();
                return parent::_prepareCollection();
        }
```

Collections.php:,

```
class Promocode_Promogenerator_Model_Mysql4_Promogenerator_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
    {

        public function _construct(){
            $this->_init("promogenerator/promogenerator");
        }



    }
```

I echo out mysql query for the above code, using `$collection->load()->getSelect();`, that prints  `SELECT`main_table`.* FROM`promo_code_details`AS`main_table`WHERE (status != '3') LIMIT 20`.

Also used `walk()` method, that throws the following error,`Fatal error: Call to a member function setPageSize() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid.php on line 553`

I don't know what I am missing,.. can someone point me, why the `setPage()` not working?..

Thanks

Comment: `$collection->setPageSize(20)->setCurPage(1);` add  curpage too

Comment: Thanks for the reply @QaisarSatti.. I tried that too but no change It display all the records

Comment: did you extend this block with toolbar block?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand. what toolbar block? @QaisarSatti

Comment: i mean you are showing the `toolbar` on that?

Comment: repalce `return parent::_prepareCollection();` with `return $this;`

Comment: I replaced `return parent::_prepareCollection();` with `return $this;` but returns same answer as before

Comment: can you add complete block code??

Comment: check my updated question @QaisarSatti

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean? Do you always see all rows on the first page in the grid?

Answer (score 3):

you can add limit `$this->setDefaultLimit(200)` for grid.

```
public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->setId("promogeneratorGrid");
            $this->setDefaultSort("id");
            $this->setDefaultDir("DESC");
            $this->setDefaultLimit(200);
            $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @QaiserSatti. I have updated my code as your answer. But no changes at all.. It load the full database table on the grid.

Comment: make all changes to before remove the limit from collection also `return $this;` change to `return parent::_prepareCollection();`

Comment: yes I removed the changes , done before. But Its not working.

Comment: make code to work on default 20 limit of grid

Comment: I tried that too..

Comment: `protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
            $collection = Mage::getModel("promogenerator/promogenerator")
                        ->getCollection()
                        ->addFieldToSelect('*')
                        ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('neq' => '3'));
                        
            $this->setCollection($collection);
            
            return parent::_prepareCollection();
            
    }` use that code and check the default limit is working and make sure cache id disabled.

Comment: `protected function _prepareCollection()
  {
    $collection = Mage::getModel("promogenerator/promogenerator")
       ->getCollection()
       ->addFieldToSelect('*')
       ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('neq' => '3'));
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
  }`  The above code only I am using, I cleared the cache

Answer (score 1):

May be try like this ,

```
$collection->getSelect()->limit(20);
```

Comment: Check if your model collection id extending from Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract class

Comment: yes the model collection id is extending `collection abstract class`, also updated model `collection.php` at my question

Answer (score 1):

The grid sets the page size in `_preparePage()` based on request parameters and default size, so changing it in `_prepareCollection()` does not have any effect.

```
protected function _preparePage()
{
    $this->getCollection()->setPageSize((int) $this->getParam($this->getVarNameLimit(), $this->_defaultLimit));
    $this->getCollection()->setCurPage((int) $this->getParam($this->getVarNamePage(), $this->_defaultPage));
}
```

See [Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/d6654602d3f3b612da41d576ae65ebc4241abf25/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php#L553)

So you either have to override this method or override the value of `_defaultLimit`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understood your explanation. But I want to select only 20 records from the table for this module only. How to achieve it?

Comment: As I said, override _preparePage(): `$this->getCollection()->setPageSize(20); $this->getCollection()->setCurPage(1)`